# Getting the status of a command vs return value of the command

Tags: tcsh

I have tcsh code below.

All I want to do is assign the SUCCESS or FAIL of the "mail" command to a variable called 'mail_status' and use the 'mail_status' value to print a STDOUT message.

Expectation is mail command returns 1, if any of the recipients in the "to" list is an invalid one. If all recipients are valid, then status return is 0.

1. I tried the code by uncommenting all "_TRY_1". It did NOT work the way I wanted to and 'mail_status' was blank and hence executing the else condtion.
2. I tried commenting out "_TRY_1" and uncommenting "_TRY_2_". It did NOT even execute
3. I tried commenting out "_TRY_2" and uncommenting "_TRY_3_". It did NOT WORK

My question:
Why are _TRY_1 _TRY_2_ and _TRY_3_ not working ?

```
#! /tool/pandora/bin/tcsh

set eval_1 = PASSED
set eval_2 = PASSED
set mail_status = 7

if ($eval_1 == "PASSED" && $eval_2 == "PASSED") then
    echo "1"
    # _TRY_1_ set mail_status = `mail -s " PASSED, 1: $eval_1, 2: $eval_2" foo@foo.com < tmp1.log`
    # _TRY_2_ set mail_status = eval "mail -s " PASSED, 1: $eval_1, 2: $eval_2" foo@foo.com < tmp1.log"
    # _TRY_3_ set mail_status = `mail -s " PASSED, 1: $eval_1, 2: $eval_2" foo@foo.com < tmp1.log`
else
    echo "2"
    # _TRY_1_ set mail_status = `mail -s " FAILED, 1: $eval_1, 2: $eval_2" foo@foo.com < tmp2.log`
    # _TRY_2_ set mail_status = eval "mail -s " FAILED, 1: $eval_1, 2: $eval_2" foo@foo.com < tmp2.log"
    # _TRY_3_ `mail -s " FAILED, 1: $eval_1, 2: $eval_2" foo@foo.com < tmp2.log`
endif

# _TRY_3_ set mail_status = $status

echo ""
# _TRY_3_ echo "mail_status = $status"
echo ""

if ($mail_status == 0) then
    echo ""
    echo "EMAIL SENT"
    echo ""
else
    echo ""
    echo "FAILED SENDING EMAIL"
    echo ""
endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the exit code from the last program use `$status` or `$?`:

```
mail -s [..trim..]
set mail_status = $status
```

`$?` is the same as `$status`, and more familiar for Bourne shell users, so it's arguably a bit better.

With `` set mail_status = `mail ..` `` you capture the *output* of the command, not the exit status.

I find it's usually best to explicitly capture the `$status` as soon as possible, to prevent accidental overriding by other commands by future changes to the script.

Comment: Hi Martin: Why does 'eval "command"' does NOT work ? I'm NOT really clear, when to use 'eval' ? Thanks

Comment: @Mike `eval` is for when you have a string (e.g. `set cmd = "ls /"` and want to run that as a command. For most shell scripts, you never need it (just `$cmd` is actually the same as `eval "$cmd"` for many purposes).